# Can I remove texlive-doc using 2.5 GB?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, disk-space, latex, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to upgrade to Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish, but I don't have enough disk space. Can I safely remove /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/ using a whopping 2.5 GB? I use Latex every day so if removing this implies I won't be able to use Latex anymore, please state so.

Comment: Is [this](https://howtoinstall.co/en/texlive-doc-fi?action=remove) what you're asking?

Comment: Without the doc tree, you will still be able to compile documents. What won't work is opening the package documentation with `texdoc packagename`

Comment: (for license reasons you might want to keep the documentation of koma script)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the 2.5 GB of documentation PDF files are required dependencies for a number of TeXlive packages. The simple solution is scorched earth:

```bash
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/*
```

The alternative would be as follows:

```bash
sudo apt purge "texlive-*-doc"
```

Don't do that though, as it will result in many other packages being `no longer required`.

An even better solution would be to switch from LaTeX, which is slow, outdated, and bloated, to [Typst](https://github.com/typst/typst/), which is modern, fast, and memory-safe.